# Problem only while using require_once() within functions.php

Tags: functions, themes, hooks, child-theme

I use `add_theme_page()` within my child theme's `functions.php` implemented something like this...

```
// other functions located here that create a custom options page in the Dashboard.
// THIS IS NOT A FILE PATH ISSUE ->  THE CUSTOM PAGE IS CREATED IN BOTH CASES.

function my_menu() {
    ...
    if ( 'save' == $_REQUEST['action'] ) {
        echo '<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0;url=themes.php?page=functions.php&saved=true">';
        die;
    }
    add_theme_page(...)
}

add_action('admin_menu', 'my_menu');
```

[As per the WordPress docs](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_theme_page):

> NOTE: If you're running into the *»You do not have sufficient
>   permissions to access this page.«* message in a `wp_die()` screen, then
>   you've hooked too early. The hook you should use is `admin_menu`.

This is exactly the error I'm getting right after saving my options.  However, I've used the correct hook as recommended.

This error only occurs if I move my function into a new file and do use a `require_once` within `funtions.php`.  I was organizing my code as per [this answer](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/1406/11092).

```
require_once('includes/functions-theme-options.php');
```

Why does this break simply by moving the function into an external file?  I thought maybe it had to do with placement, but the `require_once()` is in the exact position where the original code was placed.

- When the code is inside of `functions.php`, it works fine.
- When the code is moved to an external file and reference with `require_once()`, it breaks (*error messages upon save as per the referenced docs above*).

Obviously, for now, I'm keeping it within `function.php`, but maybe somebody can explain why it's breaking when I move it.

---

**EDIT**

**This is not a file path issue**.  Every file referenced by `require_once()` is being found and included.  The problem seems to be how it's being executed.

Please read this answer:  https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/1406/11092

---

**EDIT 2 - revised 1/16/13**

This is a stripped down version that was verified to fully demonstrate the issue.  This code constructs a submenu page under "Appearance" called "Theme Options".  When you click the "Save Options" button, the page is supposed to reload and show a *"your-theme settings saved"* message.  However, instead it shows the WordPress error page, *"You do not have sufficient permissions to access this page."*  Simply moving the last function into `functions.php` clears up this permissions issue. I would like to know why and how I can fix it.

in `functions.php` file:

```
<?php

require_once('includes/functions-test.php');
```

in my child-theme-directory, `includes/functions-test.php` file:

```
<?php

$themename = wp_get_theme();

function mytheme_admin() {

    global $themename;

    if ( $_REQUEST['saved'] ) echo '<div id="message" class="updated fade"><p><strong>'.$themename.' settings saved.</strong></p></div>';

    ?>

    <div class="wrap">
        <h2><?php echo $themename; ?> Options</h2>
        <div style="border-bottom: 1px dotted #000; padding-bottom: 10px; margin: 10px;">Options specfic to this theme.</div>
        <form method="post">
            <p class="submit">
                <input name="save" type="submit" class="button button-primary" value="Save Options" />    
                <input type="hidden" name="action" value="save" />
            </p>
        </form>
    </div>

<?php               
}


function wp_initialize_the_theme_load() {
    if (!function_exists("wp_initialize_the_theme")) { 
        wp_initialize_the_theme_message();
        die;
    }
}

add_action('admin_menu', 'mytheme_add_admin');


/*  move only the following function to 'functions.php' and the problem is gone
__________________________________________________________________________*/ 

function mytheme_add_admin() {
    global $themename, $shortname;  
    if ( $_GET['page'] == basename(__FILE__) ) {    
        if ( 'save' == $_REQUEST['action'] ) {
            echo '<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0;url=themes.php?page=functions.php&saved=true">';
            die;
        } 
    }
    add_theme_page($themename." Options", "Theme Options", 'edit_theme_options', basename(__FILE__), 'mytheme_admin');
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I noticed the URL of the custom Dashboard page is this...

```
themes.php?page=functions-test.php
```

Notice how the `page` is the name of my external functions in `includes/functions-test.php`.

The problem is in this line, the one that refreshes the page just before the permission error...

```
echo '<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0;url=themes.php?page=functions.php&saved=true">';
```

Now it seems so obvious.  Look at the `page` parameter in the URL... it's `functions.php` where it should be the name of my includes file, `functions-test.php`.

This is the fix...

```
echo '<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0;url=themes.php?page=functions-test.php&saved=true">';
```

Now I wonder if there's a more robust solution than having a hard coded file name.

**EDIT:**

And without a hard coded filename... in other words, using `basename(__FILE__)` instead and I could have moved this code anywhere without the headache.

```
echo '<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0;url=themes.php?page=' . basename(__FILE__) . '&saved=true">';
```

Thank-you to troubleshooting suggestions by @ChipBennett.

**EDIT 2:**

Taking it one step further, I was able to completely remove the `meta` `refresh;` and `die;`, where instead I use the `action` of the `form` element as it was intended.  This is the same form `action` as used in the default WordPress Appearance pages.

```
<form action="<?php echo esc_url( add_query_arg( 'saved', true ) ) ?>" method="post">
```

`add_query_arg( 'saved', true )` means that when the page redirects back to itself, on form submission, it will have `&saved=1` appended into its query string.  This is the only part this code needs in order to display the `"options saved"` message.  The very sloppy `meta refresh; die` *with its hard coded URL*, the root of the original problem, has been fully eradicated.

**FYI:**  This is a project where I must extract the client's original options and functionality from their "custom" theme and move them into a child theme of Twenty Thirteen.  The original broken theme that uses these sloppy coding practices is called [Delicate](http://wordpress.org/themes/delicate).

Comment: @Sparky Most of your questions and answers suffer from comment explosion. Please keep it under control and work more with edits to your question/answer than with comments. Thanks.

Comment: @kaiser, hyperbole... in fact, "most" of my eight questions/answers have very few to no comments at all.  I strive to conduct myself here as well as I do on StackOverflow where I've built up a respectable 28K rep.  Admittedly, this particular question contained many comments because a "more experienced" user, who couldn't see the real problem, insisted on arguing something that was clearly excluded by my OP.  It takes more than one user to make a "comment explosion" but the one with the low rep will take the blame... I'll keep that in mind moving forward.  Thank-you.