# Include files in functions.php

Tags: php, include

This is a rewritten post since the way I worded my old post totally confused everyone.

MikeSchinkel shows how he uses Include files in his theme's functions.php file In this Stackexchange post: [Organizing Code in your WordPress Theme's functions.php File?](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/1403/organizing-code-in-your-wordpress-themes-functions-php-file)

Example:

```
require_once('includes/my-file.php');
```

How would you write this php line if the file to include is inside a directory, inside the wp-content directory? Location: [wordpress install]/wp-content/new-directory/my-file.php

The only way I can think of is like this:

```
require_once( ABSPATH . '/wp-content/new-directory/my-file.php' );
```

Would this be the correct way?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Including a file inside a subdirectory is the same as any other as long as you know the path to the file. Since it's possible to [move the 'wp-content' directory](https://wordpress.org/support/article/editing-wp-config-php/#moving-wp-content-folder), don't pass that part of the path to the `require` statement; instead, use the `WP_CONTENT_DIR` constant.

```php
require_once WP_CONTENT_DIR . '/new-directory/my-file.php';
```

Also, you can leave out the parentheses since `include` and `require` are [statements, not functions](http://php.net/manual/en/function.require.php).

Comment: The hint to the const is right. But you like much more flexibility then think about a loader of your files. Is easier to maintain and no overhead. A small hint to a example here: https://github.com/bueltge/simple-masonry-wordpress-theme/blob/master/functions.php