# Include Class File in Wordpress

Tags: php, include

I'm including a Class file in `functions.php` file

```
require_once get_template_directory() . "/core/classes/General.php";
require_once get_template_directory() . "/core/classes/User.php";
```

When I do `$user->getCredits($user_id);` in some page, it works fine. But when I tried doing that same line of code in `header.php` it prompts an error of `Call to a member function getCredits() on null`.

So what I did is I required the same file in `header.php`, it still gives the same error, when I removed the included file in `functions.php` the error was removed and the code in header.php works (`$user->getCredits($user_id)`) but then in normal pages it does not detect the required file.

Any solution for this stuff?

Comment: may be your `$user` object isn't created till where you tried to call in header.

Comment: sounds like a [scope](http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php) issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please clarify where you initiate the object $user in both ways (function.php and header.php).

This is another thread on stack with similar kind of issue, have a look:

[Organizing Code in your WordPress Theme's functions.php File?](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/1403/organizing-code-in-your-wordpress-themes-functions-php-file)

Thanks,
Vee